# Unable to start Selenium session in R

Tags: r, selenium, session, indexoutofboundsexception

I've been trying to set up a Selenium session with Rwebdriver, but so far with no success. I believe I have initiated a Selenium server, but whenever I run

```
`> Rwebdriver::start_session(root = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/")`
```

I get the following error:

`Error in serverDetails$value[[1]] : subscript out of bounds`

After I set `options(error = recover)` to run a debug, I get the following result:

```
function (root = NULL, browser = "firefox", javascriptEnabled = TRUE, 
  takesScreenshot = TRUE, handlesAlerts = TRUE, databaseEnabled = TRUE, 
  cssSelectorsEnabled = TRUE) 
{

server <- list(desiredCapabilities = list(browserName = browser, 
    javascriptEnabled = javascriptEnabled, takesScreenshot = takesScreenshot, 
    handlesAlerts = handlesAlerts, databaseEnabled = databaseEnabled, 
    cssSelectorsEnabled = cssSelectorsEnabled))

newSession <- getURL(paste0(root, "session"), customrequest = "POST", 
    httpheader = c(`Content-Type` = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"), 
    postfields = toJSON(server))

  serverDetails <- fromJSON(rawToChar(getURLContent(paste0(root, 
    "sessions"), binary = TRUE)))

  sessionList <- list(time = Sys.time(), sessionURL = paste0(root, 
    "session/", serverDetails$value[[1]]$id))

  class(sessionList) <- "RSelenium"

  print("Started new session. sessionList created.")

  seleniumSession <<- sessionList

}
```

The issue is at `paste0(root, "session/", serverDetails$value[[1]]$id))`, and true enough, whenever I print `serverDetails$value`, all that appears is `list()`. Does anyone know how to fix the issue? Thank you for your attention and patience in advance.

Comment: I tried to use Selenium in R in several ways and, in my opinion, the best way is using RSelenium via Docker: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-docker.html

Comment: I used to have a lot of problems while trying to run RSelenium, not anymore. While I don't understand your particular error I can tell you how I run RSelenium on my side. I've downloaded a **Selenium Standalone Server** (a .jar file) and the last **chromedriver** (or firefoxdriver, its an .exe file). I start selenium in windows using **CMD** with the command `java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=route/to/chromedriver.exe -jar route/to/selenium.jar -port 4444` then on R I set the driver with `remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")` and then open it with `remDr$open()`. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Cris, I get the following error when I tried to follow your advice: `No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
Error in resContent[["status"]] : subscript out of bounds`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MaurícioSchwartsman well, it seems that your selenium server isn't running properly. In CMD the routes should be separated by backslashes (in my previous example I used forward slashes, my bad) like `java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\User\Folder\chromedriver.exe -jar C:\User\Folder\selenium.jar -port 4444`. Also, you need to have java installed.

Comment: @MaurícioSchwartsman Also, in my examples, the codelines are for chromedriver, not for firefox, I don't exactly know the changes in the code to run it with firefox.

Comment: @Cris, I've managed to open the browser. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MaurícioSchwartsman Awesome, I'm glad to hear that!